# which is better to send mail on google-app-engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

this: http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html

```
The web server can use an SMTP server, or it can use a local installation of Sendmail.
```

i download the Sendmail lib,and find it is so big, and so many doc,

i want to know which way is better,

and  if the Sendmail way is better, how to use it simplely,

thanks

**updated:**

if can't setup the sendmail lib,can't use this method (mail.send_mail) ,yes?:

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

mail.send_mail(sender="support@example.com",
              to="Albert Johnson <Albert.Johnson@example.com>",
              subject="Your account has been approved",
              body="""
Dear Albert:

Your example.com account has been approved.  You can now visit
http://www.example.com/ and sign in using your Google Account to
access new features.

Please let us know if you have any questions.

The example.com Team
""")
```

Comment: All of that only applies to the dev_server anyway.  For a production app, that's exactly how you send email.  While you won't be able to test without sendmail, your app will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wooble points out, this only applies to sending email from the development environment - so pick whichever option is easiest. If you can't get any of them working, email sent on the development server will still show up in your logs, so you can debug it there.